# Something behind the unity title bar

Tags: unity, 11.10, titlebar, cr-48

I recently upgraded my Google Cr-48 to Ubuntu 11.10 from Ubuntu 11.04. It appears as if there is something behind the title bar. Is this normal?

I also need to ask how I can take a screenshot to show this. I don't have a <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> key.

Comment: Try typing 'screenshot' in the dash for a screenshot-taking tool.

Comment: @MisterCrazy8 Can you also provide more details as to what exactly you're seeing behind the title bar, especially if you don't have a screenshot?

Comment: This should be split up into two questions

Comment: Hey @MisterCrazy8 - can I ask how you upgraded your CR48 to 11.10?  I tried, but don't have enough space to download the files...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a screen shot type "Screenshot" into the search bar. (Its the one with a camera ;) )

It's possible you are seeing some of Gnome panel (but without seeing I cannot say for sure.) This is because gnome panel runs underneath unity panel! So if you set the opacity of unity to 0, you'd be able to see gnome. Weird eh!

Comment: I think this is the answer to the questions it does look like the icons that the Gnome Panel displayed.

Comment: I feel confident that this is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can reassign the screenshot shortcut in system settings under keyboard->shortcuts-> screenshot

Answer (score 1):

It might be the Nautilus menu bar. When running in Classic mode with Nautilus on the desktop a Nautilus menu bar would be hidden behind the top panel, moving the panel out of the way would reveal it. So while it might be 'normal' it's certainly a bug.

Answer (score 0):

@BrianH If you use the SD card slot as a extra disk you will have extra space.

For example, chromedisk is a 16 Gig SD card

```
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda7             10321208   3940068   5856916  41% /
devtmpfs                969872       528    969344   1% /dev
none                    970092       536    969556   1% /dev/shm
none                    970092       168    969924   1% /var/run
none                    970092         0    970092   0% /var/lock
/dev/sdb1             15313808   2033372  12502536  14% /media/chromedisk
```

Comment: Thanks for answering this Ralph!  I didn't notice until now, but I still want to upgrade, so thanks for the tip!